# How do I set Grunt/Compass to watch files but not compile them directly?

Tags: sass, compass-sass, gruntjs, yeoman

I've got some SCSS files set as imports for my main SCSS file, so I don't need them to compile down to CSS.  In fact, they will get an error because they reference variable that don't work outside being imported.

How to I set grunt.js to not compile them directly?

CodeKit seems able to do this automatically, but I'd rather stick with grunt.

Comment: possible duplicate of [False positive "undefined variable" error when compiling SCSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss)

Comment: Can you post an example of how you've named your files, especially your import files?

Answer (score 1):

Rename the files that you wish to only import so that they start with an underscore. Files starting with an underscore are not compiled, but are treated normally by import statements. 
The only caveat is that you can't have the same name with and without the underscore in a folder or the import statement will be unhappy.