# How do I make a Bootstrap sass variable visible to another imported sass file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-sass

I am using `bootstrap-sass` in a Rails application. So far, everything has worked fine, but I have just tried to import another third-party sass file that uses bootstrap variables and it cannot see them.

In my `application.css.scss`

```
*= require bootstrap_local
```

In `bootstrap_local.css.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-social";
```

When I do a page access, I get a Rails error

```
Undefined variable: "$line-height-computed".
(in .../app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-social.scss:11)
```

The variable needed by `bootstrap-social.scss` is defined in the previously imported `bootstrap` file (in fact it's defined in a partial `bootstrap/variables` that it includes).

As far as I understand, this should work because `bootstrap_local` is *required*, which means that everything in it is compiled together in one scope, so everything *imported* into `bootstrap_local` is treated as being one large file. Perhaps I have this wrong?

If I throw an `@import "bootstrap";` into `bootstrap-social.scs` then it works fine. But I should not need to do this, so I either doing something wrong or I there is some misconfiguration with my setup.

**What do I need to do to fix this?**

Gems:

- bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.1
- sass-rails-4.0.3

System:

- Rails 4.0.1
- ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-linux]

([Bootstrap Social](http://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social) is a set of social sign-in buttons made in pure CSS based on Bootstrap and Font Awesome.)

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Comment: I read that. Specifically [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17976934/712506) which mentioned renaming the file with an underscore prefix but it made no difference. I will have another go, however...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem described in the question can be resolved by changing the `application.css.scss` manifest to use `import` instead of `require`:

```
@import "bootstrap_local";
```

It is also necessary to remove any `require_tree .` from the manifest because it would otherwise *require* the same `bootstrap_local` file because it lies in its path.

On reflection, not having `require tree .` in the manifest is probably wise because it prevents unwanted files from being included. I only had it there because it's there by default in a new Rails project (the same goes for `require_self`; it's cleaner not to put that in the manifest).

In reference to the suggestion about prefixing the file with an underscore, this *is* a good thing to do when the you don't need file, like `bootstrap-social` in the question, to be a compiled into a separate CSS file. So, I did end up renaming it to `_bootstrap-social.scss`.