# Zurb Foundation error: no mixin named panel

Tags: sass, package, zurb-foundation

On `"foundation": "5.3.0",` why does the following produce  `error: no mixin named panel` when the Sass is compiled (via gulp-sass)?

```
//#app.scss
@import 'foundation/scss/normalize.scss';
@import 'foundation/scss/foundation.scss';
@import 'foundation/scss/foundation/functions'
@import 'purveyor/p.scss';
```

---

```
//#p.css
.content-box {
   @include panel();
}
```

Seems like I'm missing some import, but which?

also perhaps worth including:

```
//# foundation/scss/foundation.scss
@import
  "foundation/components/grid",
  "foundation/components/accordion",
  "foundation/components/alert-boxes",
  "foundation/components/block-grid",
  "foundation/components/breadcrumbs",
  "foundation/components/button-groups",
  "foundation/components/buttons",
  "foundation/components/clearing",
  "foundation/components/dropdown",
  "foundation/components/dropdown-buttons",
  "foundation/components/flex-video",
  "foundation/components/forms",
  "foundation/components/icon-bar",
  "foundation/components/inline-lists",
  "foundation/components/joyride",
  "foundation/components/keystrokes",
  "foundation/components/labels",
  "foundation/components/magellan",
  "foundation/components/orbit",
  "foundation/components/pagination",
  "foundation/components/panels", //<--- shouldn't this be providing the mixin?
  "foundation/components/pricing-tables",
  "foundation/components/progress-bars",
  "foundation/components/range-slider",
  "foundation/components/reveal",
  "foundation/components/side-nav",
  "foundation/components/split-buttons",
  "foundation/components/sub-nav",
  "foundation/components/switches",
  "foundation/components/tables",
  "foundation/components/tabs",
  "foundation/components/thumbs",
  "foundation/components/tooltips",
  "foundation/components/top-bar",
  "foundation/components/type",
  "foundation/components/offcanvas",
  "foundation/components/visibility";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Comment: Well, what do you know! That's the ticket.

Answer (score 2):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss), Sass compiles each .scss file it finds *if it does not start with an underscore* so when it finds `p.scss` it compiles it in the absence of the other imported names. The fix was changing the name of the file to `_p.scss`