# Rails error in a SASS file when integration-testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline, integration-testing

I have a Rails 4.1.1 app and am testing it with the Minitest and Capybara gems. Running these specs gives me this error message:

```
Pages integration::GET /#test_0001_sucessfully visits the home page:
ActionView::Template::Error: Undefined variable: "$cols14".
  (in /Users/me/websites/rails/myapp/app/assets/stylesheets/modules/layout.scss:3)
```

That variable is a SASS variable and there's nothing wrong with it (it works in the layout, and there are no error messages from the SASS preprocessor).

I'm guessing this is a failure by the Asset Pipeline to compile the stylesheets properly. Here's my `app/assets/stylesheets` directory structure:

```
├── application.css
├── base
│   ├── debug.scss
│   ├── globals.scss
│   ├── normalize.scss
│   └── viewports.scss
├── inquiries.css.scss
├── libraries
│   └── responsive-nav.scss
├── modules
│   ├── layout.scss
│   └── typography.scss
└── screen.scss
```

...and here's how I import them in application.css:

```
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require 'screen'
 */
```

How do I get the tests to run error-free?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Comment: It is, using partials solved the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with extra files being generated by SASS. For each file above, SASS is generating a corresponding CSS file. As not every SASS file imports every other SASS file, we end up with variables that aren't set.

The correct way is following the principle "multiple files in development (SASS), one file in production (the generated CSS)". Hence, the new directory structure:

```
├── application.css
├── base
│   ├── _all.scss
│   ├── _debug.scss
│   ├── _globals.scss
│   ├── _normalize.scss
│   └── _viewports.scss
├── modules
│   ├── _all.scss
│   ├── _layout.scss
│   └── _typography.scss
├── screen.scss
└── vendor
    ├── _all.scss
    └── _responsive-nav.scss
```

I had figured this out before, but because errors like this don't crop up immediately (thanks to the way the Asset Pipeline compiles assets), I had postponed dealing with it up-front. Lesson: deal with broken windows early on.