# Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'mixin_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, pre-compilation

I'm working on a Rails 4 project where I'm using Sass and Sass's @import to combine multiple css into one. It works fine but not if I use a new partial for mixins (`_mixins.css.scss`) and @import this in `main.css.scss` only and use mixins any other file which is added after that `_webapp.css.scss`

```
    @import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
    @import "responsive/mega_menu";
    @import "responsive/mixins";
    @import "responsive/webapp";
```

Rails Precompilation process is unable to find "`responsive/mixins`" and gives error in `_webapp.css.scss`

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'mixin_name'.
```

here `mixin_name` is defined in `responsive/mixins`

Comment: possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss/17976934

Answer (score 2):

If your file is named `mixins.css.scss`, then you can only import it when it is called as `mixins.css`, since SASS tries to interpret the @import statement. If there is no extension, SASS expects it to be `[filename].scss`. You are trying to import `[filename].scss` while your name is `[filename].css.scss`. So try:

```
@import "responsive/mixins.css";
```

Answer (score 1):

If your stylesheets other than main.css.scss use mixins from your mixin partial then you'll have to import it within those as well. So it looks like you'd need to import mixins in your webapp partial.

Comment: Yes that's the solution I'm using it for now. But that's not the ideal and optimal way to use Sass and mixins

Comment: How is it not ideal? Mixins by themselves are not output as CSS. If your webapp partial is reliant on those mixins, then you have to include them. There's no real way around that.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an asset pipeline issue to me. From [the Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> If you want to use multiple Sass files, you should generally use the Sass @import rule
>   instead of these Sprockets directives. Using Sprockets directives all Sass files exist within
>   their own scope, making variables or mixins only available within the document they were defined in.

Are you sure you don't have a sprocket directive somewhere, requiring `responsive/webapp` (even implicitly in a `require_tree`)?

The other possibility that comes to mind is that this undefined mixin error may actually be called *before* it's imported. Are you sure you're not using that mixin somewhere in `mega_menu`?