# Heroku build failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a Rails 5 app and I'm trying to deploy it for the first time on Heroku. It gives me the following log, not sure where is the issue.

```
   I, [2017-01-16T12:43:13.155285 #3787]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/public/assets/admin/pages/media/works/img6-d846d51b577b94b6f4ec648085738337926f2d75510b067f6bf76bcc87644a80.jpg

   rake aborted!

   Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'theme'.

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/app/assets/stylesheets/admin/global/plugins/jquery-notific8/_themes.scss:12:in `theme'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/app/assets/stylesheets/admin/global/plugins/jquery-notific8/_themes.scss:12

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:351:in `block in visit_mixin'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `block in with_mixin'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `with_mixin'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:349:in `visit_mixin'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `block in visit'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:160:in `visit'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:169:in `block in visit_children'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:181:in `with_environment'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:168:in `visit_children'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:188:in `visit_root'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:159:in `visit'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sass-3.4.23/lib/sass/engine.rb:281:in `render'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/compass-rails-3.0.2/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:48:in `evaluate'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/tilt-2.0.5/lib/tilt/template.rb:102:in `render'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy_tilt_processor.rb:25:in `call'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:23:in `block in call'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/utils.rb:200:in `dfs'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/bundle.rb:24:in `call'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.0/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'

   /tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'

   Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile

   (See full trace by running task with --trace)

!

!     Precompiling assets failed.

!

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

!     Push failed
```

Can you please help me fix it? I tried finiding 'theme' but didn't understand where to look.

How can I identify and fix this issue?

Here is the content of  app/assets/stylesheets/admin/global/plugins/jquery-notific8/_themes.scss

```
/**
 * @author Will Steinmetz
 * 
 * Themes for the notific8 plug-in for jQuery
 * 
 * Copyright (c)2013, Will Steinmetz
 * Licensed under the BSD license.
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
 */

@include theme(teal, #09c, #069);
@include theme(amethyst, #915faa, #5D2D77);
@include theme(ruby, #d10, #a10);
@include theme(tangerine, #ffb23f, #e88f00);
@include theme(lemon, #ffde00, #ffcc00, #ffde00, #333);
@include theme(lime, #38d315, #32b512);
@include theme(ebony, #666, #121212);
@include theme(smoke, #ababab, #efefef, #ababab, #333, #fff);
```

Comment: Did you look here? `/tmp/build_14044c73ce6e495d61ab25d40db08259/app/assets/stylesheets/admin/global/plugins/jquery-notific8/_themes.scss:12`

Comment: There's something wrong within you sass file: Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined mixin 'theme'. Check _themes.scss line-number 12

Comment: I just added content of the file. I don't see what's wrong in it.

Comment: Looks like a solution maybe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994186/sasssyntaxerror-undefined-mixin-mixin-name