# rails 4 and compass, how import only one time my sass files?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, compass-sass, compass

I have a rail 4 project with "stylesheets/application/index.css.scss" with my all css files:

```
 /*
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require_tree ../shared
 *= require_tree ../design
 *= require_tree ../layout
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

rails compile all css in only one, minimized (in prod).

I need to import `@import "shared/header"` in many files.

exemple: in "stylesheets/layout/main.css.scss"

```
@import 'shared/header';

.header
{
  @extend .header_common_overview;
  [...]
}
```

but I `@import 'shared/header'` in others files too. The result is :

when rails compile in only one file, there are many times the same rules ".header_common_overview", because I import it in different files.

I tried to put the "import" instruction directly in index.css.scss, but it does't works.

So how can I import only one time a file, and be abble to call the content in all others  files?

Answer (score 1):

First, don't use `require_tree .` You lose control over the include order of your CSS files, potentially leading to cascading issues - styles being overwritten that really should not be.

I've learned to avoid sprockets' `require` lines in the main SASS files for reasons similar to what you describe.

- It can lead to duplication, particularly when using `=require_tree` all over the place
- Variables/mixins/etc... can't be included via sprockets *(I'd love to be proven wrong about this though)*

In your `index.css.scss` you might consider simply putting

```
@import "vendor";
@import "shared";
@import "design";
@import "layout";

// Your main styling here.

@import "another_file";
```

These `@import` lines correspond to other sass files. `shared.css.scss` for example might look like

```
/*
 *=require ./shared/header
 */
```

The idea is to

1. Keep clean separation/organization of your asset includes
2. Explicitly define each asset include so you retain full control over include order
3. Use SASS `@import`instead of Sprockets `=require` directive to keep variables, mixins, etc... present in an included file available throughout.

Comment: include one by one my css file is realy borring way. We can't @import an folder? I have 20 css files, I have to put 20 @import?

Comment: Check [the manual](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5) and [this SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4779432/605707) that describes the same limitation with importing a directory at once that I described about Sprockets above.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is : create all.css.scss with :

```
/*
 *= require jquery.ui.all => static, don't need import
 */
@import 'included/**/*'; //all files included (at first time)
@import 'all/**/*'; //all real css files which requires included file (in second times)
```

The order is respected and controlled.

The included files is present only one time

the included files are shared in each real css files.

thx for help.