# Compass is not able to find mixins

Tags: sass, compass-sass, gulp

I am trying basic sass + compass in gulp to build css. When i run the task I get an error `Error: error main.scss (Line 2: Undefined mixin 'user-select'.)`
I have both sass and compass installed. Same story is happening with gulp-compass.

Any ideas what is wrong with my configuration?

Minimal configuration that is behaving this way for me:

My gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'); 
var sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
gulp.src('./scss/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ compass: true, sourcemap: true, style: 'compressed' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});
```

My sass file:

```
%button {
  @include user-select('none');
}

.button-orange {
  @extend %button;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

I don't have config.rb for compass. Looking for a way of setting it up without it.

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss/17976934

Comment: It's different case than what is in that link.

Comment: what do you have in your `config.rb` next to your Gulpfile ?

Comment: I don't have config.rb. I was trying to make it work without it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing first line of the scss form `@import "compass/css3/user-interface";` to this line `@import "compass/css3";` helped for this problem

I also run `$ compass create` - at this point I am not sure that this changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can omit using of Compass compiler at all. Just import Compass into your SASS file.

1. Install the library:

   ```
   bower install compass-sass-mixins
   ```
2. Import the compass into your SASS file:

   ```
   @import "bower_components/compass-sass-mixins/lib/compass"
   ```