# Rails - Heroku fails to compile sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, sass

I get an error when Heroku is trying to compile assets of my Rails app:

```
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$btn-default-border".
remote:        (in /tmp/build_8402012299c8c367a1dc15dd7f5cd85f/app/assets/stylesheets/auctions.css.scss:42)
remote:        /tmp/build_8402012299c8c367a1dc15dd7f5cd85f/app/assets/stylesheets/auctions.css.scss:42
```

When I run `rake assets:precompile` locally it works.

Here my application.css.scss

```
/*
 *
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker3
 */
@import "variables"; 
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "auctions";
```

auctions.css.scss

```
.form-control-feedback {
    pointer-events: all;

    &:hover {
        cursor:pointer;
        border: 1px solid $btn-default-border;
        background: $gray-lighter;
        border-radius: 5px; 
    }
}
```

Why is it working locally but not on Heroku? Is Heroku trying to compile `auctions.css.scss` without other dependencies?

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss/

Answer (score 2):

Try bumping `Rails.application.config.assets.version` in `config/initializers/assets.rb`.

I had the same exact issue deploying to Heroku right after I switched Sprockets `require` to `@import` lines in my application manifest file. (I had issues with CSS rule precedences and realized I was doing something wrong. This article directed me to better conventions: https://content.pivotal.io/blog/structure-your-sass-files-with-import)

I fixed it by bumping the `Rails.application.config.assets.version` in my `config/initializers/assets.rb`.

Bumping the version prompted my app to reprocess all asset files, which seemed to reset its understanding of certain files and their dependence on variables.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that production.rb have the following code or else add it

```
 # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
    config.assets.precompile += %w( *.css *.js )
```

Comment: I read that it should not have it otherwise Rails will try to compile `auctions.css.scss` without loading dependencies. I try it anyway and get the same error.  I also try `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.js ) Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( application.css )` in config/initializers/assets.rb and it also failed.

Answer (score 0):

go to the file `config/initializers/assests.rb`

add line or update.
`Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += [/.*\.js/,/.*\.scss/]`

and run
`bundle exec assets:precompile`