# @import compass/css3 not found

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm working on a drupal project using SASS and Compass.  I would like to use compass mixins like:

```
  @include transition-property(width);
  @include transition-duration(2s);
```

But when I try to `@import 'compass/css3';` at the top of my scss file, it does not work.  I guess this is because _css3.scss file is not in my  drupal theme's scss folder.  It's in systems (ubuntu) */var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/stylesheets/compass* folder.

1. How should I include compass/css3?
2. Should I edit the *config.rb* file?
3. What will happen if another developer works on this project who has their compass *_css3.scss* file in a different location?  Will they need to edit their local *config.rb* file or *scss* files?

Comment: If you're using the `compass` command to compile, you shouldn't be getting any such error.  Are you sure your problem is not this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss ?

Comment: @cimmanon, I'm not seeing any errors in the terminal when I run the compass command `compass watch sites/all/themes/project/`.  My `config.rb` file is in the _project_ folder.

Comment: If there's not an error, I don't understand what the problem is.