# How to use sass variables in my own scss files

Tags: sass, materialize

I just started with materialize but now I'm faced with a problem.

When I want to use: `@media #{$small-and-up} {` media query in my own scss file I get the following error: `Error: Undefined variable: "$medium-and-up".` While I'm importing the `materialize.css` file which is compiled from `/sass/materialized.scss`.

So my question is how can I use the variables / media querys in my own scss file? 
I compile the scss by the file watcher plug-in in PHPStorm or by sass compiler installed in command prompt windows.

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Comment: @cimmanon doesn't change a thing

Comment: If the provided answer does not answer your question, there is not enough code here to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SASS variables don't exist in compiled CSS files. If you want to use variables defined in `materialized.scss` in your own SCSS stylesheet, you need to insert `@import "sass/materialized.scss"` in your stylesheet.

Incidentally, if you do this, you probably won't need to compile `materialized.scss` any more. Just compile your SCSS stylesheet, which, because of the `@import` statement, will pull in `materialized.scss`.

**UPDATE:**

After reviewing code at https://github.com/SuperDJ/dsuper/blob/master/private/admin/css/sass/opening.scss, it seems the problem is with this line:

```
@import url(/private/admin/css/material/sass/materialize.scss);
```

This is not valid syntax in SCSS. It should be:

```
@import "../material/sass/materialize";
```

Comment: @SuperDJ what's the error message? Still `Error: Undefined variable`?

Comment: Like I said still the same error message like the import doesn't work

Comment: Are you importing `materialized.scss` at the top of your stylesheet?

Comment: yes I have some comments on top. But before I do any styling I import materialized.scss

Comment: Hmm, sounds like it should work. I might have some more ideas if you have your code publicly available somewhere.

Comment: here: https://github.com/SuperDJ/dsuper/blob/master/private/admin/css/sass/opening.scss

Comment: Does it work if you change this:

`@import url(/private/admin/css/material/sass/materialize.scss);`

to this:

`@import "../material/sass/materialize";`