# Is it possible to use variables from an import in another import?

Tags: sass

For example:

main.scss

```
@import "variables";
@import "page";
```

_variables.scss

```
$color-a: #FFFFFF;
```

_page.scss

```
div.test {
  background: $color-a;
}
```

Or does `variables` have to be imported on every sheet that wants to use a variable from it?

Currently, I'm getting `Error: Undefined variable: "$color-a"`

**Edit** I should add that I'm using `sassc` to compile the files in a clojure project:

```
:sass {:sass-file "main.scss"
    :source-maps false
    :output-style "compressed"
    :output-dir "css/"}}
```

Comment: Are you using a task runner to handle your SASS?

Comment: Yes, it's using `sassc` in a clojure project

Comment: What you've done should be working to be honest. I've just created the same set up and run it on the command line and it was fine.

Comment: Do you have `sass` installed globally so you can run it through terminal? If so, run `sass path/to/main.scss output.css` and see if you still get the error.

Comment: I don't know if sassc does something unusual, but this should not happen with vanilla Sass (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss/17976934)

Comment: Add a semicolon after each `@import` statement and try again. Running `sass` from the terminal without them threw errors for me.

Comment: @jh3y Missing semicolons won't produce the error the OP claims to be getting (`Line 2: Invalid CSS after "@import "colors"": expected selector or at-rule, was "@import "buttons""` vs `Line 3: Undefined variable: "$color_blue".`)

Comment: Fair point. It was just something else I noticed. No reason it shouldn't be working really.

Comment: @cimmanon sorry my mistake while writing this post, my file does indeed have the semicolons.

Comment: Try compiling it with vanilla Sass and see if you get the same error.  If not, you might want to file a bug report with the maintainers of sassc.