# Compiling directories with SASSC

Tags: sass

I'm having trouble getting SASSC to compile my scss when I point it at a directory containing many scss files.  If I specify just the top-level file that imports all the others, then it compiles fine, but that breaks the watch functionality of the build tool I'm using ([lein-sass](https://github.com/101loops/lein-sass)).  This is because if I only tell it to watch the top-level file (rather than a whole directory), then it only picks up changes in the top-level file which we rarely update.

It looks like the problem is that it's not compiling things in the correct order, so dependencies are missing.

Is there something about how I should structure my scss files so that SASSC can figure out which file to compile first?

My structure is something like:

```
my-app.scss
pages/page1.scss
pages/page2.scss
components/common.scss
```

The `my-app.scss` file imports all the others, but they all depend upon the `common.scss` file in the components folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Comment: Oh I think I see, things that are depended upon but are not standalone should be prefixed with underscores to indicate to sass that they should be compiled first for use elsewhere. I'll test this out and report back, thanks.