# SASS using a function within a variable definition

Tags: function, sass, variable-declaration, node-sass

I'm using node-sass and trying to build a set of styles which are easily re-themed, meaning that for example, changing one colour will update various others.

I have a function which takes a colour (the background colour), determines the lightness, and outputs a pre-set dark or light colour to be used as the text colour.  I've used this same function before and it works well.  It is included in the sass file, and have tested that it works.

```
@function color-contrast($color) {
  @if (lightness($color) > 50) {
    @return $color-text-dark; //if the background is more than 50 lightness, return the dark colour
  }
 @else {
   @return $color-text-light; //if not, return the light colour
 }
}
```

However, I'm now trying to use this function WITHIN a variable declaration.  So I have

```
$contentbox-text-color: color-contrast($bg-color) ;
```

($bg-color, $color-text- etc are set earlier in the sheet)

Problem is, wherever I use $contentbox-text-color, I'm seeing as the color value

```
color-contrast(blue);
```

(where "blue" is the $bg-color value) - rather than the result of the function, which I would expect to see.  I've tried interpolating the function as shown below, but the result is the same

```
$contentbox-text-color: #{color-contrast($bg-color)} ;
```

I need to access this function via a variable, as I then use the variable (/resulting colour) as an argument for a mixin, and in various other places.

Does anyone know of any way to achieve what I'm trying to do?  I can't find any information on using functions within variables, so I don't know if this is something which isn't possible, or if I'm just missing some syntax that would make it work correctly!

Thanks :)

Quick update: This compiles correctly if I call the function directly as an argument in the mixin, but ideally I'd like to be able to simply use the variable name, so that the same variable can be used throughout (if for some reason it changed, which is possible, it would be a pain to have to go to every mixin and update the arguments rather than simply rely on the variable!)

Comment: Hi Cimmanon

I've looked at the question you linked to, but the issue in that question was that the function wasn't defined, and the only answer relates to this.  

I have confirmed that my function exists and is working, as it works when used stand-alone and also when called directly in the mixin, but not in the way I am attempting.

Comment: You need to provide a clear [MCVE] then.  The only possible way to get a variable that contains the string `color-contrast(blue)` is if the color-contrast function does not exist.  Possible alternate duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss