# Webpack sass loader does not recognize global variables file

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack

i have this sass directory:

```
- _vars.scss
- main.scss
```

//vars.scss

```
$base-container: 1400px;
```

//main.scss

```
@import './vars';
```

In other js file i have:

```
require('./some-module-sass-file');
```

//some-module-sass-file.scss

```
.container {
  width: $base-container;
}
```

The problem is i have global variables in the **vars file** and the **some-module-sass-file** not recognize them and throw an error:

```
undefined variable $base-container
```

Comment: What error? Btw, it's not obvious how you import `vars` file but have the `_vars` file (note on the leading underscore).

Comment: That's not a complete error message for sure. To be helpful - provide it entirely and format it properly as a part of the question.

Comment: So the `some-module-sass-file.scss` does not import global vars file.

Comment: No, the main.scss does

Comment: And `some-module-sass-file.scss` does not. It's not obvious why main's imports should affect anything else.

Comment: I don't see where some-module-sass-file.scss is being imported by any file that also has _vars.scss imported.  The main.scss file is not importing that (or if it is, you haven't shown that).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to import the `vars` file into every Sass partial that uses those variables, because every partial is compiled on its own; none of the files will 'know about' the others unless you specifically import them.

If you don't want to have to type the `import`s in every Sass file, you can look at [baggage-loader](https://github.com/deepsweet/baggage-loader), which will automatically add them for you.

Comment: What about third party libraries? I'm having trouble because some deep dependency can't resolve it's built in variables...

Comment: @tutuca not sure I can help without more info. the TLDR here is that every single Sass file that you require with webpack is compiled in isolation. I would imagine that if you're including 3rd party sass there's no reason it shouldn't work as expected, so long as you include it everywhere you use it

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you could unwittingly break precedence rules based on load order. For example if you override something in twitter bootsrap in one file and then in another scss file you override a different thing in twitter bootstrap, now your first override is overruled by having to import bootstrap at the top of the second scss file. At least that's what I'm seeing in my own applications.

Comment: @cdmo worth noting that modular/component-based architectures tend to avoid those kinds of order-based behavior. For example, giving every element a descriptive class name (not ID) and targeting elements specifically, rather than relying on the cascade and inherited styles. You do lose some of the 'elegance' of CSS, but being able to develop and reuse independent modules is a good trade off IMO.

Comment: Fair point, it's something to avoid, "semantic classes" is generally a smoother path. :100:

Answer (score 17):

**Without using sass-resources-loader**:

Thanks to [@Arseniy-II](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8163773/arseniy-ii) for helping me get to this answer, in conjunction with this thread:
https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/218

Using loader options in your webpack module rules, you can assign a data property to sass-loader, you should then be able to use all sass functions as expected:

```
module: {
  rules: [
    // Apply loader
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            data: '@import "path/to/global.scss";',
            includePaths:[__dirname, 'src']
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer? Thank you sir.

Comment: I guess this is not an accepted answer because the global provided to data would create duplicates

Comment: Works for me with rewriting bulma's css vars

Comment: Be careful with this approach as it injects code and will therefore break your source mappings

Comment: In webpack 4, [Options such as data and file are unavailable and will be ignored.](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#sassoptions)

Answer (score 11):

Note that you need to use `"` and `;` at the end

```
{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
        additionalData:'@import "path/to/general.sass";',
    },
},
```

Comment: I had to use path.resolve rather than just a string: resources: [path.resolve(__dirname, './../vars.scss')]

Answer (score 8):

If you have Webpack 5 you have to use **additionalData**, the other options are not valid now:

```
  {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        additionalData: '@import path/to/general.sass',
      }
  },
```

If you do like this your general sass or scss file will get prepended

Comment: Please update your answer to the correct syntax 
additionalData: '@import "path/to/general.sass";',

Answer (score 1):

Webpack 4 solution:

```js
{
    loader: 'sass-loader', options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        prependData: '@import "pathto/vars";'
    },
}
```

In order `@import "pathto/vars";` to work you need Webpack to configure to resolve such imports. So it simply prepends the line.

This solution is good because you have no issues with sourcemaps like with using `sass-resources-loader`

Answer (score 0):

You can use text-transform-loader package.

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  use: [
      'style-loader',
      'css-loader',
      'sass-loader', 
      {
        loader: 'text-transform-loader',
        options: {
          prependText: `@import "${path.resolve(__dirname, './base.scss')}";`,
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```