# Global SCSS mixins in nuxt 2.8

Tags: javascript, sass, nuxt.js

nuxt.config.ts:

```
  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [
    '@/assets/scss/global.scss'
  ],
```

mixins in global.scss:

```
@mixin grid($flex) {
    @if $flex {
        @include flex;
    } @else {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Then if i try to use this mixin in a component's scss - it throws an error about missing mixin. Is there a way to use global mixins/variables in nuxt?

Answer (score 2):

To use mixin you should `@import` mixin file inside scss file you are trying to use your mixin.

You can import your mixins (and/or variables) globally by using [sass-resources-loader](https://github.com/shakacode/sass-resources-loader)
For more info check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533428/webpack-sass-loader-does-not-recognize-global-variables-file/48861607#48861607)