# Storybook with vue - SassError: Undefined variable

Tags: vue.js, sass, storybook

I am using storybook with Vue. I have some common SCSS I want to use.

```
I am using the addon in **main.js**

  addons: [

    '@storybook/preset-scss'
  ],
```

This seems to automatically pick up **./src/scss/variables.scss** which for testing I have added

```
body {
  border: 10px solid green;
}
```

This works and hot reloads too the issue is any variables are not found in my components.

So my story list.stories.js imports the list component

**import List from '../components/List.vue'**

but within the style block I am trying use a var from the variables.scss.

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.list {
  border: 1px solid  $light-blue;
 
}
</style>
```

And get the error

```
SassError: Undefined variable: "$light-blue".
        on line 204 of components/src/components/List.vue
>>   border: 2px solid  $light-blue;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack sass loader does not recognize global variables file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533428/webpack-sass-loader-does-not-recognize-global-variables-file)

Comment: What makes you think that `./src/scss/variables.scss` is somehow automatically loaded ? I do not see anything supporting your conclusion in the [docs](https://github.com/storybookjs/presets/tree/master/packages/preset-scss)

Answer (score 1):

In `main.js` add `sass-loader` to webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  webpackFinal: async (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: [
        'style-loader',
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            additionalData: '../src/scss/variables.scss',
          },
        },
      ],
    });
    return config;
  }
}
```

It works with installed `css-loader@5`, `sass-loader@10` and `style-loader@2`.

Answer (score -2):

If `scss` is not working, then you can load styles by creating `preview-head.html` file at `config/storybook/preview-head.html`

And then just load your CSS there. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/media-screen.css">
```

Make sure to restart Storybook dev server. `npm run storybook:serve`