# Since upgrading to webpack 5 global variables in sass no longer work

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

My stylesheets do something like:

```
# application.scss
$color: golden-brown;
@import 'waffles';
```

```
# waffles.scss
.yummy { color: $color }
```

I am using webpack with sass-loader, and previously this would work just fine-- but since upgrading to webpack 5, I am now getting `Undefined Variable $color`

Sass' documentation says:

> Variables declared at the top level of a stylesheet are global

So if this is true, why am I getting Undefined Variable errors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack sass loader does not recognize global variables file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533428/webpack-sass-loader-does-not-recognize-global-variables-file)