# How to use sass variables with scss files imported through JS?

Tags: javascript, webpack, sass

I'm working on my first "real" project with webpack and I have an issue using sass variables depending on where I use them.

This is part of my folders so you can understand:

```
new_folder/
├─ assets/
│  ├─ styles/
│  │  ├─ _base.scss
│  │  ├─ _reset.scss
│  │  ├─ _variables.scss
│  │  ├─ styles.scss
├─ index.html
├─ index.js
├─ index.scss
```

I'm adding my sass variables in **_variables.scss** while **_base.scss** contains all the common css for my project (header, footer, components/ui elements)

Then I import everything in styles.scss, using `@import` because with `@use` I apparently have some troubles so I will replace it later).

```scss
@import 'reset';
@import 'variables';
@import 'fonts';
@import 'icons';
@import 'base';
```

Then I'm loading styles.scss on all the pages at the beginning, not in the scss file as an import but directly in JS, which is what I learnt on the course I previously followed :

```js
import './assets/styles/styles.scss';
import './index.scss';
import { db } from './assets/javascripts/firebase';

import { doc, collection, getDocs, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore';

const placesArray = [];
const cardsContainerElem = document.querySelector('.cardsContainer');
```

But i get the error that the variables, when used in index.scss are undefined, while it works when I use them in _base.scss

I guess I could always import directly in the scss file of every page, but I learnt to import through JS, so I'm questioning if there is a reason to do this way

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webpack sass loader does not recognize global variables file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35533428/webpack-sass-loader-does-not-recognize-global-variables-file)

Comment: I seen one of the answers in the thread talking of sass-resources-loader (he did an example without but it's no longer working on webpack 4), so I downloaded it. It seems working for my variables now, but I have errors related to fonts and icons because the path seems wrong. I'm not able to identify how the way it is imported has impacted this.

Comment: Is just importing the variables into each file out of the question? It takes some getting used to, but it makes more sense for how bundlers work which is each file has its own scope. This may feel odd at first, but is harmless and the same way you'd deal with JS imports. This is essentially the pattern the default sass loader is trying to lead you down, and you should ask yourself if fighting it is worth the effort.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was afraid of, spending time on something that looks more comfortable than useful. Ideally, I think it's better to have one file that load all the essential things you need (separated in different files for readability, such as variables, mixins, reset..), and then you just call your file everywhere and you have only one to import. Maybe fill a bit stupid or too boxy but I feel it's important to start to do this from the beginning of a project because it can quickly be a mess. So I'm trying to find the best way to do it (and the one that makes more sense, if it exists)

Comment: However, importing styles.scss directly into my index.scss instead of index.js doesn't work : it creates an issue about my fonts because it doesn't find the path (which was not the case when I used the import from JS)