# Gulp Sass failed to @extend class when same version as team

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm trying to run our gulp sass task and I keep getting the following error:

```
".features" failed to @extend ".text-center".
The selector ".text-center" was not found.
```

The selector appears in a file which is `@import`ed before the file that throws the error.  They are both `.scss` files and loaded in the correct order (I can get sass to throw a syntax error before the `.text-center` class definition.

What is really strange is the fact that this is a shared repo (which I'm up to date on in the master branch) and we all have the same version of sass (managed by npm):

```
$ node-sass --version
node-sass   3.5.3   (Wrapper)   [JavaScript]
libsass     3.3.5   (Sass Compiler) [C/C++]
```

We're out of ideas of why only my version throws this error, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Order of imports doesn't matter for extends.  There's not enough information here to reproduce a problem.  Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/envoyer/latest-node-sass-update-broke-production-environment

Comment: I am getting the same issue at the moment. 

I have a main.scss which imports _icon.scss and later _button.scss. a class in _button.scss extends a class from _icon.scss, but I get an error saying: "'.button--dropdown' failed to @extend '.icon--font' - The selector 'icon--font' was not found". However, **other partials loaded before _button.scss which also extend icon--font are processed without error**. 

What other information would be useful to solve this?